# Is it true that desert animals can drink seawater?

Tags: nutrition

In physiology books (Medical Physiology - Guyton and Hall) one studies that according to renal capacity features, some desert animals are capable of drinking seawater. Is this also true in practice? Or is this just a theory?

> However, a shipwreck victim’s pet Australian hopping mouse could drink with impunity all the seawater it wanted.

Comment: animal is a pretty wide classification, fish are animals and I would guess that sea fish can drink sea water.

Comment: if you just wanted an answer, yes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_turtle

Comment: Actually it says the opposite: they cant drink sea water according to renal features

Comment: Are we reading in the same language? "Hatchlings depend on drinking sea water immediately upon entering the ocean" your question could be tightened up you asked "can animals drink seawater" my answer is "yes" , i do note that "reptilian kidneys cannot produce urine with a higher ion concentration than sea water" so they rely on crying out the salt

Comment: Crying out the salt? They have salt glands. Anyways read my question again: it says "according to renal capacity features, some animals are capable of drinking seawater" this is not the case as, according to their renal concentration capacity: they can't

Comment: I should have stuck to whales instead of turtles, silly turtles always letting me down https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-can-sea-mammals-drink/

Comment: Your question needs quotes and/or links, and indeed, you should specify what animals. Please use your energy for that (so that people need what to write an answer to) instead of arguing in comments.

Comment: "I read a book once that says .." does not make the question notable unless you can show us the book and demonstrate that it's worth discussing.

Comment: I like this question now, the interesting thing is hopping mice live in a desert, which doesn't touch a sea. So some humans would probably have to experiment to find an answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Eyre_basin#/media/File:Lake_eyre_basin_map.png

Comment: In context, the weird wording makes more sense. They do a *calculation* to show why a ship-wrecked human would be dehydrated, and then then show *in theory* why the ship-wrecked human's hypothetical pet would be fine.

Comment: This question has a couple of problems - but they are subtle. The first is that title says "desert animals", the body says "some desert animals", but the claim is only the Australian Hopping Mouse. The second is that it isn't a serious claim that Hopping Mice can drink seawater (in fact the same page explains the mouse can survive without drinking any water at all). It is just an illustration of how the "Obligatory Urine Volume" calculation works, with regards to the excretion of sodium, without any claim that real life Hopping Mice would actually attempt to drink seawater.

Comment: In short: No-one believes hopping mice (let alone all desert animals) drink sea-water, so there is no need for us to debunk it.

Comment: No one except Guyton and Hall and everyone who bought into their book

Comment: @gurghet: I believe you have misunderstood the section.

Comment: Might be a better question for the Biology site.